# Odoo Pos Receipt blank line between wrapped product name

Tags: odoo

Why Odoo prints a blank line between each product name wrapped text? see the sample receipt. Is it related to the ticket width or orderlines ratio?

Also in the order lines the quantity is shown in one line and the pricetotal in another line, I would expect this code would show the quantity and total price of the product on the same line but again the quantity is shown in one line and the product total price in the next line, why? is it also related to the receipt width or may orderlines ratio which I don't understand the purpose by the way.

```xml
<div class='orderlines' line-ratio='0.6'>

<line indent='1'>
    <left>
        <t t-esc='line.quantity' />
    </left>
    <right>
       <t t-esc='line.price_display' /></value>
    </right>
</line>
```

[Sample Receipt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7qjG.jpg)

Comment: I think reason is size of ticket becasue as your product name is much larger then expected size so this might cause issue. Also try to remove 'indent' and then try again so it might works.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, where do I find the product name expected size in order to increase it?

Comment: You can do css there.

Comment: Can I do thai with the XmlReceipt? I'm printing directly to the printer using a PosBox.

Comment: No. You can do that "PosTicket" template.

Comment: So how to do I do with PosTicket?

Comment: Just apply some CSS to there. Might work